# How to read text files in a folder and write to Kafka Topic on windows

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I have a locally setup Kafka on my windows 10 machine. Currently I am still learning Kafka and testing its capabilities on my local machine.

I was able to create a topic and run producer and consumer through command prompt successfully using below commands.

```
.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties

.\bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test

.\bin\windows\kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
.\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test
```

Now I am trying to stream the contents of text files generated in network folder to the Kafka Topic.

I have read about [Spool Dir Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-spooldir/current/index.html#:%7E:text=The%20Kafka%20Connect%20Spool%20Dir,placed%20into%20the%20configured%20finished.), but couldn't figure out how to configure it on windows machine.

Alternate option I was thinking about is to read files using python and then write it to Kafka using kafka-python. In this case I am not sure about the performance impact and also how to track which files are processed and which are not.

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import os

source_dir = 'C:/PATH/TO/SOURCE/FOLDER/'

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
    value_serializer=lambda x: str(x).encode('utf-8'),
    key_serializer=lambda x: str(x).encode('utf-8'))

for filename in os.listdir(source_dir):
    with open(filename, mode='r') as f:
       data = f.read()
       producer.send('test', value=data)
```

What is the right approach to do this? Any help is appreciated

**Edit:**
I tried configuring confluent platform on windows based on [this documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/zip-tar.html?_ga=2.82316880.730450909.1620630556-1268936781.1612170782&_gac=1.249236981.1619673082.CjwKCAjwj6SEBhAOEiwAvFRuKH7ttlMboG0t4YLCAq1x6-DIFqBAtYgsYLrhDOEsYAbGJk91-JXoNBoC2XgQAvD_BwE) as confluent platform is necessary for configuring Spooldir. I am getting below error while starting zookeeper

> Classpath is empty. Please build the project first e.g. by running 'gradlew jarAll

Comment: If you want to use the spooldir connector, what issues are you having with it? Otherwise, yes, you need to implement your own file tracking solution in Python (maybe try sqlite)

Comment: For spooldir, I couldn't find any documentation on how to configure it on windows machine. Please share if there is any documentation on spooldir pre-requisites and configuration on windows.

Comment: Follow the documentation you did find, but use `bin/windows/connect-standalone.bat` to run the Connect server

Comment: Thanks. The SpoolDir Connector Documentation says Confluent Hub Client is a pre-requisite. But the installation instructions are available only for Mac and Linux. Is it possible to use spooldir directly on windows?

Comment: All connectors are available without using the client. All the client does is [download and extract a zip file, which you can do manually](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-spooldir/current/index.html#install-the-spool-dir-connector-package)

Comment: Thanks. I understand the confluent platform needs to be configured for using spooldir. But I am getting error while doing that. Please see Edit in question

Comment: Confluent Platform doesn't support Windows, and you don't need anything related to Confluent to run the Spooldir connector. You download the connector zip file here https://www.confluent.io/hub/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the right approach to do this?

Your Python code isn't going to track file offsets or successful reads of a file, so using some other spooldir connector would be best

Also worth pointing out that Kafka records have a default max size of 1MB, and it's generally an anti-pattern to use it for file transfers. Rather, use some shared NAS or blob/object storage for files, and send URI locators through Kafka

> read about Spool Dir Connector, but couldn't figure out how to configure it on windows machine

Instructions should be the same as Linux, just different file paths and scripts. Confluent hub cli doesn't have a Windows binary, so you'll need to set it up manually

> confluent platform is necessary for configuring Spooldir.

It's not. Besides, Confluent Platform is still using Apache Kafka and Zookeeper, so any errors you would get from it, you should have gotten before

---

[Download the connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir)

Extract the zip

Find and edit `connect-standalone.properties`

Edit the `plugin.path` to include the `C:\\path\\to\\kafka-connect-spooldir` (make sure this is the parent directory of where the JAR files are)

In the extracted folder, you should have another properties file. Configure that

Once you've configured both properties files, use them to run a standalone connect server

```
bin\windows\connect-standalone config\connect-standalone.properties spooldir.properties
```